# Under what conditions does MPI_Isend/MPI_Irecv wait for its associated completion call (MPI_Wait/MPI_Test) to start data transmission?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing

One of the comments in [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8308/when-is-mpi-wait-necessary-for-non-blocking-calls) post briefly mentions

> The standard allows the implementation to postpone the actual data transmission until the wait/test call.

Is it always the case that data transmission of `MPI_Isend`/`MPI_Irecv` is postponed until the associated completion call (`MPI_Wait`/`MPI_Test` or their variants) is invoked? If not, what conditions influence this?

Comment: the standard does not guarantee messages are progressed asynchronously. Some MPI implementations feature a progress thread to achieve this. In the case of `MPI_Isend()`, a message can be send in eager mode. Generally speaking, communications are progressed when a MPI subroutine is invoked.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thank you for this information. I am struggling to find information on how to call `MPI_Isend()` in eager mode. Can you advise me on this?

Comment: Eager vs non eager is an implementation choice. A rule of thumb is only “small” messages are sent in eager mode, but there is no guarantee.

Comment: I see, but is `MPI_Test()` the only way to force `MPI_Isend` to send in eager mode (while still remaining non-blocking)? As in, would the eager mode implementation be `MPI_Isend` immediately followed by `MPI_Test`?

Comment: `MPI_Test()` does not force an eager send, it progresses communications. most other mpi subroutines also do that, for example `MPI_Wait()`, `MPI_Recv()` or even `MPI_Send()` to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

- `MPI_Wait` is used to wait for a single communication to complete
- `MPI_Waitall` is used to wait for a list of communications to complete
- `MPI_Test` and `MPI_Testall` use in non-blocking communications to check if the communications are finished without requiring them to be finished.

With the `MPI_Isend`, You had to store the values of each of the data points as a separate variable in an array

- This is because the data can be sent anytime until the `MPI_Waitall` is called.
- This means that the data mustn’t be changed/overwritten or go out of scope within this interval.
- This is different from `MPI_Send`, where the data to be sent is buffered and/or actually sent by the time `MPI_Send` completes.

The same is true of `MPI_Irecv`, though this is more obvious as you want to have the data.

**Note**

In MPI_Testall the flag will be true only if all the communications are finished.